# Historical data for outstanding shares on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Looking for a way to pull historical data from google finance on an annual basis. Looking to have a sheet similar to the image below

[image]

I'm trying to use the function `=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1, "Shares",date(  ) )` for outstanding shares but keep getting #n/a

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, this is not supported in `GOOGLEFINANCE`. see:

[image]

**https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB**

Comment: is there a work around for this? The image I posted is on google sheets pulling historical data automatically. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AkashDhingra nope, shares are not supported under historical data. but maybe you could find a website which holds such data and not runs on JavaScript - such website can be scrapped into google sheets

Answer (score 0):

I use [TIKR](https://app.tikr.com/) which has good 10+ year financial data. It has a useful feature `Copy Table` which can be pasted into Google Sheets.

I use a `temp` sheet for this, so I can extract the rows/cols I want using script.