# How do I get market cap of a stock of 6 months ago using google sheet

Tags: function

I am trying to get market cap of a stock of six months ago using google sheet

The implementation below shows market cap of a stock at present time.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, "marketcap")
```

How do I get market cap of a stock that was 6 months ago? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Marketcap is an attribute of real-time data

The syntax for GOOGLEFINANCE is :

```
GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, [attribute], [start_date], [end_date|num_days], [interval])
```

**ticker** - The ticker symbol for the security to consider. It’s mandatory to use both the exchange symbol and ticker symbol for accurate results and to avoid discrepancies. For example, use “NASDAQ:GOOG” instead of “GOOG.”

**attribute** - [ OPTIONAL - "price" by default ] - The attribute to fetch about ticker from Google Finance and is required if a date is specified.

**attribute is one of the following for historical data:**

"open" - The opening price for the specified date(s).

"close" - The closing price for the specified date(s).

"high" - The high price for the specified date(s).

"low" - The low price for the specified date(s).

"volume" - The volume for the specified date(s).

"all" - All of the above.

**attribute is one of the following for real-time data:**

"price" - Real-time price quote, delayed by up to 20 minutes.

"priceopen" - The price as of market open.

"high" - The current day's high price.

"low" - The current day's low price.

"volume" - The current day's trading volume.

"marketcap" - The market capitalization of the stock.

"tradetime" - The time of the last trade.

"datadelay" - How far delayed the real-time data is.

"volumeavg" - The average daily trading volume.

"pe" - The price/earnings ratio.

"eps" - The earnings per share.

"high52" - The 52-week high price.

"low52" - The 52-week low price.

"change" - The price change since the previous trading day's close.

"beta" - The beta value.

"changepct" - The percentage change in price since the previous trading day's close.

"closeyest" - The previous day's closing price.

"shares" - The number of outstanding shares.

"currency" - The currency in which the security is priced. Currencies don't have trading windows, so open, low, high, and volume won't return for this argument

**start_date** - [ OPTIONAL ] - The start date when fetching historical data.

If start_date is specified but end_date|num_days is not, only the single day's data is returned.

**end_date|num_days** - [ OPTIONAL ] - The end date when fetching historical data, or the number of days from start_date for which to return data.

**interval** - [ OPTIONAL ] - The frequency of returned data; either "DAILY" or "WEEKLY".

interval can alternatively be specified as 1 or 7. Other numeric values are disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Finance function in Google Sheets doesn't actually return historical market cap info like this. You can only get the current market cap for a company.

The wording in the documentation makes it confusing. It had me googling for an answer for some time.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081607/historical-data-for-outstanding-shares-on-google-sheets) is a related thread that highlights the language in the documentation and made it clearer to me.